# Why my for-loop has only one result after a python list iterator?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The following codes with for-loop only return one-item while I expected it could return many-item. For example,
It returned actually:

```
0.3273
```

What I expected is

```
0.8372
0.2847
0.1837
0.3273
...
```

Should I use .append() or something else? Please give me some detailed code advice. Thank you.

```
def phrase_similarity(phrase):
    phrase_vec = phrase_model[phrase]
    for a_word in phrase_model.keys():
        a_val = phrase_model[a_word]
        cos_dis = cosine_similarity(phrase_vec, a_val) #it's numpy.ndarray
        cos_dis_str = str(cos_dis.tolist()).strip('[[]]')

    return cos_dis_str
```

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `cos_dis_str` at each step (and `cos_dis`, for that matter), rather than accumulating results.

Comment: If you print `cos_dis` during iteration, what does it print? (just a few please, [mcve])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let cos_dis_str be an empty list

```
cos_dis_str=[]
```

Then a simple append would fix that

```
cos_dis_str.append(str(cos_dis.tolist()).strip('[[]]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When the For loop is executing, each time the os_dis_str is getting overwritten.
So make sure that you create a list for that and keep on appending onto that. Then return the list. You can access each of the individual values from there.

```
cos_dis_str.append(str(cos_dis.tolist()).strip('[[]]'))
```

Also initialize `cos_dis_str = []`, outside the For loop but within the function.
Hope this helps to get an understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code this way.

```
def phrase_similarity(phrase):

    phrase_vec = phrase_model[phrase]
    cos_dis_str = []

    for a_word, a_val in phrase_model.items():
        cos_dis = cosine_similarity(phrase_vec, a_val).tolist()).strip('[[]]') #it's numpy.ndarray
        cos_dis_str.append(str(cos_dis))

    return '\n'.join(cos_dis_str)
```